# Is it possible to crop a render texture in unity?

Tags: unity, graphics, rendertexture

Basically what I want to do is, take the source render texture from `OnRenderImage` and crop it (continuously). I've already achieved this by using `ReadPixels` to a texture however this has a negative impact in my FPS. Is there any other way that is less expensive?

Here's an example of what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain where this render texture is being displayed, and maybe show a mock-up of what you want it to look like? (eg. if you're rendering this to the screen, should the cropped version stretch to fill the whole screen, or should there be bars/gaps around the sides when it's cropped smaller than the screen/window size?)

Comment: The texture it's going to be used to feed a video, the cropped version will have gaps to the sides, it should look something like this(behold my majestic paint skills): https://i.snag.gy/ZNuioS.jpg

Comment: @BaekRyun Welcome to GDSE. As clarifications come up via comments, edit & refine your original question to include the additional information - it helps keep the question self-contained & easier to answer (which in turn makes it more likely to get answered). If you have additional resources (images, etc), [here's a handy reference for how best to include them in your question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/).